# Wordpress, setcookie and page conditionals

Tags: wordpress, cookies

i have a specific request. Want to setcookie but only if user visit certain page. Regular conditionals are not working probably have something to do how wordpress loads. I tried with several hooks init, wp , template_redirect and noone of those works. If i am logged in then it works (its not a cache issue).

```
function set_cookie_on_gift_page() {
$is_gift_page = is_page('gift');

var_dump($is_gift_page); // Output the result of is_page for debugging purposes
if ($is_gift_page) {
    setcookie('viewed_single_product_after_gift', 'true', time() + 3600, '/'); // Set cookie for 1 hour
}}
```

Also i tried regular is_page and other conditionals its always the same. However if u pust some echo 'test" those functions are working, but setcookie no.

Comment: Have you tried setting a cookie with JavaScript?

Comment: yes with javascript its working.